# Using If/Truth Statements with pandas

Tags: if-statement, pandas

I tried referencing the pandas documentation but still can't figure out how to proceed.

I have this data

```
In [6]:

df
Out[6]:
    strike putCall
0       50       C
1       55       P
2       60       C
3       65       C
4       70       C
5       75       P
6       80       P
7       85       C
8       90       P
9       95       C
10     100       C
11     105       P
12     110       P
13     115       C
14     120       P
15     125       C
16     130       C
17     135       P
18     140       C
19     145       C
20     150       C
```

and am trying to run this code:

```
if df['putCall'] == 'P':
    if df['strike']<100:
        df['optVol'] = 1
    else:
         df['optVol'] = -999       
else:
    if df['strike']>df['avg_syn']:
        df['optVol'] = 1
    else:
         df['optVol']= =-999
```

I get an error message:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

the above code and data are example only to illustrate the problem I ran into

Any assistance would be appreciated.

John

### OP add-on

The above question was answered very well by Joris, but I have a slight add-on question.

how would I call a function such as

```
def Bool2(df):
    df['optVol'] = df['strike']/100
    return(df)
```

rather than assign the value of optVol directly to 1 in the line:

```
df.loc[(df['putCall'] == 'P') & (df['strike']>=100), 'optVol'] = 1
```

I would like to have the function Bool2 called and do the assigning.  Obviously, the Bool2 function is much more complicated than I have portrayed.

I tried this (shot in the dark), but it did not work:

```
df.loc[(df['putCall'] == 'P') & (df['strike']<100), 'optVol'] =df.apply(Bool2,axis=1)
```

thanks again for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, when you want to set values using such a if-else logic, **boolean indexing** is the solution (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)):

The logic in:

```
if df['strike']<100:
   df['optVol'] = 1
```

can be expressed with boolean indexing as:

```
df.loc[df['strike'] < 100, 'optVol'] = 1
```

For your example, you have multiple nested if-else, and then you can combine conditions using `&`:

```
df.loc[(df['putCall'] == 'P') & (df['strike']>=100), 'optVol'] = 1
```

The full equivalent of your code above could be like this:

```
df['optVol'] = -999
df.loc[(df['putCall'] == 'P') & (df['strike']>=100), 'optVol'] = 1
df.loc[(df['putCall'] != 'P') & (df['strike']>df['avg_syn']), 'optVol'] = 1
```

---

The reason you get the error message above is because when doing `if df['strike']<100` this comparison works elementwise, so `df['strike']<100` gives you a Series of True and False values, while `if` expects a single True or False value.

Comment: Thank you Joris!  Did the trick (and thanks for the explanation as to why I got the error)

Comment: joris, I added another request in the OP, not sure if you can help

Comment: It's better to ask that as a new question